# How can I see all changed files between two commits, with a relative path?

Tags: git

This seems like a pretty straightforward question, with [an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23000227/2008384), but it's not *quite* the answer I'm looking for.

Here's the story:

I do most of my development on feature branches which are merged with `develop` when the work is done. Before I merge & delete the feature branch, I like to review what I've done. To get the list of files that I'll need to review, I do this:

```
git --no-pager diff --name-only develop..HEAD
```

So, for example, I might see something like this:

```
file1.js
path1/file2.js
path1/file3.js
```

This tells me that I've made changes to those files and I need to go in & review them.

The problem is that these file paths are all relative to the root of the repository. I like to do the following to open all the relevant files in my editor:

```
git --no-pager diff --name-only develop..HEAD | xargs atom
```

If I'm currently at the root of the repository, this will open all of the files in different tabs in atom, ready for me to review them.

However, if I happen to be in a different directory (say, if I `cd`ed into `path1` to do something), I get a bunch of empty tabs as `atom` attempts to open files that don't exist. I have to remember to `cd` back to the root of the repository before starting my review.

This irritated me once too often this morning, so I went looking for a solution. I found [the answer cited above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23000227/2008384) which suggests adding the `--relative` option to the command, like so:

```
git --no-pager diff --relative --name-only develop..HEAD
```

This sort of works, but it only gives me the files at or below the directory where I am in the repository. So, in the example above, if I've `cd`ed into `path1`, I'll see:

```
file2.js
file3.js
```

What I'd really like to see is:

```
../file1.js
file2.js
file3.js
```

which would allow me to pipe it to `atom` and open all the files.

I did read the `git help` documentation for the `diff` command, and the `--relative` flag *does* allow you to specify a path but it also excludes files outside the path.

Short of writing a very long command line like this:

```
pushd "$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)" >/dev/null \
    && git --no-pager diff --name-only develop..HEAD | xargs atom \
    && popd > /dev/null
```

is there a way to get a list of all files changed between two commits with paths that are relative to the current directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is nothing built in to Git to do this, but it would be easy to write a script or alias to do it.

Note that `git rev-parse --show-cdup` shows you the string of `../`-es to add to the *current* directory to get to the top level.  The result is empty if you are already at the top level.  Hence:

```
git diff --name-only "$@" | sed -e "s,^,$(git rev-parse --show-cdup),"
```

gets you close enough if you don't mind having `../sub/file.js` produced when it could just say `file.js`.  If you *do* mind, one more `-e` expression could fix that: replace `../../$whereIam/` with nothing, filling in the `$whereIam` variable from the difference between `git rev-parse --show-toplevel` and `pwd`.

Comment: Thank you! That's much better than the messy `pushd`/`popd` shuffling around I was doing.