# git diff master --name-only doesn't show relative paths like git status does

Tags: git

When I run `git status` I see what files changed relative to my cwd. This is super useful because I can copy paste those paths if I want to do something to those files.

When I run git `git diff somebranch --name-only` though it shows me the paths of the files relative to the top level dir of the repo. I was looking and didn't see a param - is there a switch to have `git diff somebranch --name-only` return the file paths relative to my cwd?

Comment: It looks like you have to filter the `git diff --name-only` output via a filter like `realpath` or `symlinks` (neither seemed to work for me) and then wrap it in an alias if it succeeds.

Comment: fine if git doesnt support it but figured id ask in case there was a hidden feature/switch I missed :)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23000086/git-diff-output-relative-path ?

Comment: Don't know why this question got downvoted as it shows the inconsistency between the defaults in various git commands.

Comment: it was a duplicate. I suppose I could have googled my way to it if I searched for something like `how to git diff relative path`